# Execute a Bash Function in new Xterm window

Tags: bash, xterm

Is there a way one can execute the bash function in the new XTERM window? Below is what I am trying to do

```
function test(){
 echo "Do some work"
}
```

Then inside my bash script, I am doing the following:

```
export -f test
xterm -title "Work1" -e "test" "$date_today" "$time_today" &
# The above I am trying to open xterm, run the function, and pass 2 parameters (date_today and time today)
```

Currently the above does not work as it complains that test is not defined. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Don't put it in a function, just:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Do some work"
```

and name the file `test.sh`. Do NOT call it just `test`. Remember to `chmod +x file.sh`. Then call it with:

`xterm -title "Work1" -e "<path_to_file>/test.sh" "$date_today" "$time_today" &`

Answer (score 0):

I use `typeset` to export functions through `ssh`, but it seems that you can use it for `xterm` as well.

```sh
$ function test(){
    echo "Do some work"
}

$ export -f test

$ xterm -title "Work1" -e "$(typeset -f test); test" "$date_today" "$time_today" &
```